# Docusign REST API failure to launch

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

Recently moved a Docusign Java sdk based apiclient solution to PROD, but after that all existing the rest api calls, including the docusign api rest calls fails with the below error

```
06-Sep-2018 12:46:50.645 SEVERE [ajp-nio-8269-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [Jersey REST Service]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:486)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After further investigation i found that our application uses JAX-RS 2 jars like 
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar while dependency for Docusign Java sdk is 
com.sun.jersey.jersey-core-1.4.0.jar which is JAX-RS 1 version. By removing the com.sun.jersey.jersey-core-1.4.0.jar , the existing rest api calls works but the Docusign rest api fails with the below error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Please suggest how to proceed from here
```

Kindly suggest a approach to make both rest api calls to work without breakage.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey 1 and Jersey 2 are not compatible at all and thus you cannot have jars related to both in the same application.

So, if possible you should think about using `jersey 1.0 (com.sun.jersey)` in your application because you don't have any control over `Docusign`.